# Shortcode don't work in custom option field, any solution?

Tags: shortcode, theme-customizer, theme-options

I have a custom field in the theme Customizer that allow to define own copyright information. I created a shortcode displaying the current year. How to make the shortcode work when someone has pasted it into textarea?

I use Kirki framework to create theme options.

```
Kirki::add_field( 'my_customizer', array(
  'type'     => 'editor',
  'settings' => 'copyright',
  'label'    => __( 'Content', 'mytheme' ),
  'section'  => 'section_footer',
  'default'  => __( 'Copyright ⓒ All rights reserved.', 'mytheme' ),
  'description' => __( 'You can use [current-year] shortcode if you want.', 'mytheme' ),
) );
```

To display above option I add this to footer.php:

```
echo Kirki::get_option( 'my_customizer', 'copyright' );
```

What I see on the site:

```
Copyright ⓒ [current-year] All rights reserved.
All rights reserved. ⓒ [current-year] by XYZ 
All rights reserved. ⓒ 2016 - [current-year]
```

What I need to achieve:

```
Copyright ⓒ 2019 All rights reserved.
All rights reserved. ⓒ 2019 by XYZ 
All rights reserved. ⓒ 2016 - 2019
```

Any solution / idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a shortcode string saved, try echoing it with `do_shortcode` function, which turns shortcodes into content.

```
$saved_shortcode = get_option( 'my_customizer', 'copyright' );
if ( $saved_shortcode && is_string( $saved_shortcode ) ) {
echo do_shortcode( $saved_shortcode );
}
```

More about the function on the developer handbook, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

**EDIT**

Another option is just echo the year directly on the footer template without first getting the shortcode string from the database and then rendering it.

Comment: That works! Thank you :)